# Getting Instamojo link in android

Tags: android, android-volley, instamojo

I have been trying to get the Instamojo link in my android application for a transaction. For testing I have been trying to send the post request to generate the link but all the time I am getting AuthFailureError. I am posting my code below.I don't know if some error is there in my codes or I am following the wrong way to integrate Instamojo in my app. Please help.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RequestQueue mQueue;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mQueue = CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(this)
            .getRequestQueue();
    String url = "https://www.instamojo.com/api/1.1/payment-requests/";
    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    try {
        params.put("purpose","selling");
        params.put("amount","20");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final CustomJSONObjectRequest jsonRequest=new CustomJSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
        {
           Log.d("animesh",response.toString());

        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "no internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("animesh", error.toString());
        }
    });
    mQueue.add(jsonRequest);
```

}
}

CustomJSONObjectRequest.java:

public class CustomJSONObjectRequest extends JsonObjectRequest {

```
public CustomJSONObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
                               Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener,
                               Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    //String creds = String.format("%s:%s","archerpenny_glide","archer@#62@glide*");
     //String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    headers.put("api_key", "**********************************");
    headers.put("auth_token", "*******************************");
    return headers;
}

@Override
public RetryPolicy getRetryPolicy() {
    // here you can write a custom retry policy
    return super.getRetryPolicy();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send the `api_key` and the `auth_token` you are doing:

```
headers.put("api_key", "**********************************");
headers.put("auth_token", "*******************************");
```

Instead, you need to do:

```
headers.put("X-Api-Key", "**********************************");
headers.put("X-Auth-Token", "*******************************");
```

You can refer to the `REST API` documentation here: https://www.instamojo.com/developers/rest/

Comment: Thank you..that was a very silly mistake..even I saw it in the documentation.. Thank you..:)

Comment: Hello i'm using your code,but i facing same problem AuthFailureError.